# Why all the java code is packed in Classes?

Tags: java, class

I have started learning Java and picked up some books and collected materials online too. I have programmed using C++. What I do not understand is that ,even the main method is packed inside a Class in Java. Why do we have everything packed inside some class in Java ? Why it does not have independent functions ?

Comment: Why C++ packs variables and functions in classes?

Comment: Note that static methods (such as the `main` method) are more or less "independent functions".

Comment: @Thilo I would also add that a class that cannot be instantiated and has only static methods is the same as having a cpp file with functions and a namespace

Answer (score 6):

This is the main concept of object oriented programming languages: **everything** is an object which is an instance of a class.

So because there's nothing but classes in Java (except the few Java primitive types, like int, float, ...) we have to define the `main` method, the starting point for a java application, inside a class.

---

The `main` method is a normal static method that behaves just like any other static method. Only that the virtual machine uses this one method (only) to start the *main thread* of the application.

Basically, it works like this:

1. You start the application with `java MyClass`
2. The JVM loads this class ("classloading")
3. The JVM starts a new thread (the main thread)
4. The JVM invokes the method with the signature `public static void main(String[])`

That's it (in brief).

Comment: Except that Java's definition of a "thing" is much narrower than in some other languages.

Comment: @Karl - The answer was designed to help a pure java beginner, not to win a discussion on *the best* OO language ;-)

Comment: The main method being the entry point for the application ,and since it lies inside a class, there is a possibility of calling the main method again and again from various instances of this class right.  (Pardon me if i sound silly, but no books or online articles explain such doubts ;) )

Comment: @shimna - yes, that's right. It's a normal static method and you may call it again and again (technically spoken).

Comment: It is even a `public` static method, so, yes, one could call it from contexts other than the JVM launching the application. It is good practice to keep the main method short (just about parsing the command line arguments), and moving the "real work" somewhere else.

Comment: Static classes (those with only static methods) are not objects though, nor instances. Not OOP at all. I really don't get the point of forcing the user to use them instead of independent functions.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how the designers of the language wanted it to be.

Comment: And why is that? What are the benefits of doing so? Was it just to make the implementation simpler? This answer provides no clarification

Comment: It sounds vacuous but this is actually a decent explanation, because there's no good reason. Java didn't have to be that way -- as demonstrated by the fact that no other mainstream language is like this. Maybe it simplifies something for the compiler's writers, but for the end user it just imposes needless complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Java enforces the Object Oriented paradigm very very heavily.  That said, there are plenty of ways to work around it if you find it cumbersome.

For one, the class that contains main can easily have lots of other methods in it.  Also, it's not uncommon to make a class called 'Utility' or something similar to store all your generic methods that aren't associated with any particular class or objects.

Comment: In that case , we create a class just for the sake of creating one right. :)   I have used a class in another language ,which has provided me convenience . Here , i am forced to create a class without knowing why i should have one.  I am trying to understand the reason behind this design decision. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you work in a smart IDE such as eclipse, you'll eventually find that Java's seemingly over-abundant restrictions, exceptions, and rigorous structure are actually a blessing in disguise.  The compiler can understand and work through your code much better when the language isn't cluttered with syntactic junk.  It will give you information about unused variables and methods, dead code, etc. and the IDE will give you suggested fixes and code completion (and of course auto-format).  I never actually type out import statements anymore, I just mouse over the code and select the class I want.  With rigorous types, generic types, casting restrictions etc. the compiler can catch a lot of code which might otherwise result in all kinds of crazy undetectable behavior at runtime.  Java is the strictest language in the sense that most of what you type will not compile or else very quickly throw an Exception of one kind or another.
So, if you ask a question about the structure of Java, Java programmers will generally just answer "because that's the rule" while Python programmers are trying to get their indentation right (no auto-format to help), Ruby programmers are writing unit tests to make sure all their arguments are of the correct type and C programmers are trying to figure out where the segfault is occuring.  As I understand C++ has everything Java has, but too many other capabilities (including casting anything to anything and oh-so-dangerous pointer arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

And you can have multiple entry points in a jar depending on how many classes inside the package has main.

Comment: I see.This looks like a good reason ,although i need to figure out why we need multiple entries.

Comment: I once tried to answer this question and I could not find a good answer apart from that it's a decision of language implementors. The only closest thing I could figure out is that, the language designers wanted it to be pure Object oriented so they want everything in the class. Multiple entry points, always looked to me more of a result of that decision than anything else. I would suggest keep this question aside for some time and concentrate on learning the other language features :). These kind of questions are like black holes. Wish you best of luck

Comment: I will keep this in mind Lalit :)  I was so disheartened when the simple helloworld program was put inside a scary class :)